# Post function on every routes

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

Currently I'm duplicating the same .post method on every route, because I want every route to have this method. Is there any other way to make all routes to have the same method without duplicating it?

Example:
for every route user could post something to the database.

api.js

```
api.route('/')
   .post(function(req, res) {
         var story = ({
            content: req.body.content;
         });
    story.save();

   });


api.route('/profile')

 .post(function(req, res) {
         var story = ({
            content: req.body.content;
         });
    story.save();

   });
```

and just for information, does every route could only perform one .get or .post method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the logic inside a function:

```
var yourFunction = function(req, res) {
   var story = ({
      content: req.body.content;
   });
   story.save();
});
```

and pass it to your route definition:

```
api.route('/').post(yourFunction);
api.route('/profile').post(yourFunction);
```

> does every route could only perform one .get or .post method?

You can have:

```
api.route('/').get(yourFunction);
api.route('/').post(yourOtherFunction);
```

but you can't have:

```
api.route('/').get(yourFunction);
api.route('/').get(yourOtherFunction);
```

In the latter, `express` will consider the last one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but let just say in one route '/' a user could post a message and a user could post a tweet. How would I accomplish that? If you want me to open a new question regarding this question, let me know.

Comment: In this case, you'd have to implement some logic inside the funcition you're passing to your route to check if the `req.body.content` is a message or a tweet, and then do what you want with the information.